# Powershell: Why is a certain string array is being formatted as "System.Int32"?

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm trying to add string members to an array called `$htmlbodytest` that I can then email at the end of the script (after all the loops close).

Why am I getting the following error message when I try to populate an array with string members (and only string members)?:

```
Cannot convert value "test server" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
```

1. I have several other jagged arrays in the script (within the loops) that store strings with no issue.
2. I have not declared anything anywhere with regard to data type.
3. If I add a test array member after the loops in the email section with just "test" it still fails.
4. If I copy this into it's own script, I can populate the array with strings just fine.

More detail:

```
# before loops begin, array is declared as:
$htmlbodytest = @()
```

[...]

```
foreach ($server_name in $server_names) {
 Start-Job -Scriptblock {
 #If server fails a ping test, skip it and add to array to email
 if(!(Test-Connection -ComputerName $using:server_name -Quiet)) {
  $htmlbodytest += "$using:server_name"
  continue
 } else {
```

[...]

```
} # after work of loop is finished, send email 
$smtpServer = "10.10.10.10"
$smtpFrom = "from@co.com"
$smtpTo = "to@co.com"
$messageSubject = "Servers that didn't record uptime this month due to no ping"
$message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $smtpfrom, $smtpto
$message.Subject = $messageSubject
$message.IsBodyHTML = $true
$message.Body = $htmlbodytest | ForEach-Object {Add-Member -InputObject $_ -Type      NoteProperty -Name Servers -Value $_; $_} | ConvertTo-Html -Head $a -Property Server 
$smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$smtp.Send($message)
```

Comment: I'm having trouble finding an issue not that thats saying much for me. Does it change anything if you change the declaration? `[string[]]$htmlbodytest = @()`. I feel like the answer might be in the code that is missing. Is there anywhere else where you try to populate `$htmlbodytest` that is not shown?

Comment: I closed ISE and re-opened and changed the variable name and it's working now. I declared $htmlbodytest in a separate tab that I didn't realize. Sorry for wasting your time, but thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Closing ISE and reopening this resolved this. I was using this same variable name in a different tab, but was always populating with string types. I'm certainly not marking this as answered out of glory, but to prevent wasting others' time on this flaky issue.